# Connecting php with html Code doesn't work

Tags: php, html, wordpress

since an Image says more than Word here you go:

[image]

I basically just want the 'IMDB' Label, if there is a Link inside the Article's Metadata otherwise it shouldn't be visible.

```
<?php $rating = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Rating', true); ?>
<?php $imdblink = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'IMDb-Link', true); ?>
<?php if($rating==""){ echo ""; if($imdblink=="") {echo "";} } else { ?>
<div style="float: right"><a href="http://soundso.de<?php  echo $imdblink; ?>">IMDb <?php echo $rating; ?>/10</a> </div>
```

Comment: Your code miss an } at the end? (for the "else" - part)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be modelled like this:

```
$rating = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Rating', true);
$imdblink = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'IMDb-Link', true);

if (empty($rating) || empty($imdblink)) {
    print "";
} else {
    ?><div style="float:right;"><a href="http://soundso.de<?php print $imdblink; ?>">IMDb <?php print $rating; ?>/10</a></div><?php
}
```

You just missed a closing brace after the `if($rating == "")` check.